# Erro Plugin VenoBox no Safari Mac OsX

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Estou com um pequeno problema neste plugin, o nome é VenoBox. Com a mesma função do ColorBox, ele abre iframes, fotos, links externos e HTML no famoso efeito lightbox.

Peguei um projeto no qual os desenvolvedores que criaram a estrutura utilizaram este plugin, e no Safari (mac osx) ele ao abrir, me parece que executa mais de uma vez a função do click, sendo assim ele exibe a modal e depois o loading por cima, e as informações que deveriam ser exibidas ficam para trás. No Console não é exibido nenhum erro do plugin, apenas erros de jquery.map que eu já coloquei o arquivo e mesmo assim o problema persiste.

Para visualizar o problema:
www.pinheironeto.com.br (links do rodape - Termos de Uso / Política de Privacidade)

Valeu e abs!

Answer (score 0):

Após alguns testes, encontramos um possível erro no plugin, que foi corrigido na linha 538 do plugin:

```
  content.animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  },'slow',function(){
    //fix to Safari on MacOS
    $(".vbox-preloader").hide();
  });

}
```

Apenas colocamos um hide na div preloader, que ficava por cima do box, resolvendo assim o problema de visualização no Safari no Mac OSX.